# Virtual box connectivity from a remote laptop

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox, vmware, vmware-workstation

I have a server(A) on which oracle virtual box is installed which is configured with 3 boxes(B,C,D) .Please check below image.

http://i63.tinypic.com/10dbjhh.jpg

I can connect to server A from my laptop ,but i'm unable to connect B,C & D servers which are configured on VBOX of server A .

Please  let me a know possible solution for this.

Comment: Yes... i'm unable to do ssh

Comment: No... but i can ping A

Comment: Server( A ) is on Rhel 5.8 and B  C D on CentOS 6.7

Answer (score 2):

SSH to server A then from inside A, use the following template:

```
ssh <username>@<IP ADDRESS OF B>
```

For example

```
ssh root@10.88.12.5
```

Comment: Yes i can Connect this way but if i want open PHP page on B from my lapy. Then how can make it

Comment: I don't understand what you mean

Comment: Sorry peter if i commented other way wrong.issue here is that i am unable to ssh B directly from my laptop.

Answer (score 2):

Flush iptables on B C D to allow ssh

```
iptables -F
```

Then restart iptables

Answer (score 1):

Try this method which may work:

Run the following command on B:
     `curl icanhazip.com`

This will give you your public IP as 10.x.x.x is a private IP address. Then try and directly SSH to the public IP. If this doesn't work, it's something to do with iptables.

Comment: Tried...but still facing same problem

Comment: Try `netstat -a |grep ssh` and see if the status is 'LISTEN'

Comment: Netstat on Server B

netstat -a |grep ssh
tcp        0      0 *:ssh                       *:*                         LISTEN
tcp        0      0 Dn1:ssh                     10.88.13.0:46224            VERBUNDEN
tcp        0      0 *:ssh                       *:*                         LISTEN

Comment: Netstat on Server A

 netstat -a |grep ssh
tcp        0      0 *:ssh                       *:*                         LISTEN
tcp        0      0 10.88.13.0:46224            Dn1:ssh                     ESTABLISHED
tcp        0    624 nn1:ssh                     lpt0122-pc.nxlpdc:56336     ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 nn1:ssh                     lpt0122-pc.nxlpdc:56327     ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 *:ssh                       *:*                         LISTEN
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     17059  /tmp/ssh-pJZnFb7627/agent.7627